# Why can't I divide 1 with a float in Python 3

Tags: python

[leetcode task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md2aT.png)

I was practicing Python3 in leetcode. I have to make a power function where I dont use "**". When the exponent (n) is positive, my code works but when its negative it doesnt. When its negative I try to divide 1 with the result, but it acts like the result is always 1. In this case instead of dividing 1 / 4 it looks like it does 1 / 1. Does any1 know where the problem is?

Comment: Try return float(1/res).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when n < 0 you have

```
for i in range(n):
```

It should be:

```
for i in range(-n):
```

**Revised Code**

```
def my_pow(x, n):
    res = 1
    if n > 0:
        for i in range(n):
            res = res*x
        return res
    if n < 0:
        for i in range(-n):
            res = res*x
        return 1/res
    return res
```